# connect oracle database with php and execute sql?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Hey guys im trying to connect to an oracle database with php. I tried it like i do it with mysql.
How to do it like this:

```
$host="localhost";
$user="username";
$pass="password";
$db="database";

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Keine Verbindung zu der Datenbank moeglich.");

mysql_select_db($db, $link);

$sql = "SQL query goes here";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

How can i do exact this with an oracle database. I have the following connection details
`sid, ip, port, username, password`.

Comment: You cannot use the MySQL extension to connect to Oracle. Period. As the name suggests, it's built for MySQL.

Comment: He just gave an example how he's doing it in mysql. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @AlenOblak - Well, he said he actually tried that code...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario this is only example how i do it in mysql

Comment: Recommended reading: [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple script:

```
$DB = '//1.2.3.4:1521/XE';
$DB_USER = 'user';
$DB_PASS = 'pass';
$DB_CHAR = 'AL32UTF8';

$conn = oci_connect($DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB, $DB_CHAR);
$statement = oci_parse($conn, 'select 1 from dual');
oci_execute($statement);
$row = oci_fetch_array($statement, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
```

Comment: And how to use the sid in the script without it i can't connect and for what stands the `/xe` for behind the ip

Comment: This is the only recommended way to connect to Oracle. The PDO driver is tagged as experimental because it's basically abandoned.

Comment: The "xe" after the IP is the SID.

Comment: OK your script gives me this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()`

Comment: You need the OCI extension on your server. Check the documentation: http://si.php.net/manual/en/oci8.setup.php

Answer (score 1):

To connect with an Oracle database, you don't use the mysql extension (since that is for MySQL). You should use PDO, with the [OCI/Oracle adapter](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use PDO to connect to Oracle here is the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) on creating a connection using PDO, the example given is for MySQL but it will work fine with Oracle. You will need to ensure the PDO:Oracle extension is installed and running on your PHP configuration.